# how to provide xml input for junit test case

Tags: xml, automated-tests

i'm new to automation and keen to learn automation by using junit and java , so help me.
my question:

> > how to provide input to text fields in web application by XML file.
> >     1. how to read the data from xml file.
> >     2. and can we use custom tags

Currently i'm trying to automate yahoo mail. I'm able to send username and password by

```
WebElement mail = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=('Email')]"));
 mail.sendKeys("harish");
```

but i want to write data in xml and read the data from xml.

Please help me.